# Perl script invocation error from Python

Tags: python, linux, debugging

When cmd is run manually it works with no issues, but when run from another program on linux it gives me an error in the logs. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comes up with this error when in logs when i check log files.

```
[WARNING ] 17:39:20 core:124 [execute] command 'perl /home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl' failed with exit code 1
[WARNING ] 17:39:20 core:128 [execute] stderr: Upon execvpe perl /home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl ['perl /home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl', '176426f007943621q60bc72d3ae333af46a0d502', 'Continuum Season 2', '/home/josh/media/!complete'] in environment id 25326672
:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 420, in _fork
executable, args, environment)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 466, in _execChild
os.execvpe(executable, args, environment)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 353, in execvpe
_execvpe(file, args, env)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 368, in _execvpe
func(file, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

UPDATE-

now i get a diff error-

```
[WARNING ] 21:43:00 core:124 [execute] command './home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl' failed with exit code 2
[WARNING ] 21:43:00 core:128 [execute] stderr: Can't locate WWW/TheMovieDB.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl line 56.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl line 56.
```

Comment: Iv changed the command on deluge by removing the 'perl' so it now just runs './home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl'

check above

I believe iv installed WWW/TheMovieDB.pm but maybe not correctly

Comment: New error: It's expecting module WWW::TheMovieDB to be installed. Install it

Comment: I did, says its upto-date

Comment: Could also be a permission problem. What is the full path to TheMovieDB.pm? (`perldoc -l WWW::TheMovieDB` might give it to you, or you can use `find` to scour your system)

Comment: its located in - /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/WWW/TheMovieDB.pm

Comment: Looks like you got two versions of Perl installed, you've installed the module using 5.18.1, but you're launching the script using 5.14.2. Either launch the script using the Perl that has the module installed (by adjusting the PATH or providing the full path to `perl`), or install the module using the Perl with which you are launching the script (`/path/to/perl -MCPAN -e'install "WWW::TheMovieDB"'`).

Comment: oh, maybe its from a previous install. wats the cmd to install it to the correct perl?

Comment: by path to perl u mean '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/' right? so id run 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/ -MCPAN -e'install "WWW::TheMovieDB"

Comment: ok maybe not. ok il figure it out. im sure google has some answers.. thx Ikegami for all ur help

Comment: Not quite. 1) The path to `perl` will end in `perl`. 2) Your command is missing the terminating quote (`'`). 3) You already have it installed using 5.18. You're launching the 5.14 Perl using `execpve`, so that's the one that needs the module. Why not just have `execpve` use the 5.18 Perl?

Comment: read ur comment again and better understood it. how would i go about changing execpve to use the correct perl?

Comment: by adjusting the PATH or providing the full path to `perl` (`/full/path/to/the/5.18.1/perl`) Can probably be obtained using `which perl`

Comment: well when i run wgich perl i get '/usr/local/bin/perl'. well i have to go to work. so il check back on this tomorrow. mostly once i can change it to the correct path i should be golden. thx again and il check back tomorrow.

Comment: Im back. time to do some more research on this execpve now and find out how to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instructed `execvpe` to look for an executable named `perl /home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl`. As you can imagine, it did not find it.

What you did was equivalent to entering the following in the shell:

```
'perl /home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl' ...
```

`/home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl` should be passed as an argument. Instead of

```
args = (...)
os.execvpe('perl /home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl', args, env)
```

You want

```
args = ('/home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl', ...)
os.execvpe('perl', args, env)
```

Comment: I didnt make the script. Im just trying to get it to work with deluge. So the problem lies with deluge or the script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the argument seperately from the command when you call the function in python. As you can see, the executable (perl) should be the first argument to execvpe, and the argument /home/josh/scripts/deluge/sorttv.pl should be the second.